# Typescript: When not making instance of object but just assigning the type when retrieving it, methods of its class Declaration don't exist. Why?

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, typescript-typings

```
class Document {
private something: string;

constructor(document: Document) {
Object.assign(this, document);
}

public someGetter() {
return this.something;
}
}

// Other file
// Let's assume it returns Object with attribute something = "something";
// DynamoDB SingleTable design noSQL btw
document: Document = getDocumentfromDatabase(id);

// "someGetter() IS NOT A FUNCTION"
myString: string = document.someGetter();
```

Meanwhile:

```
class Document {
private something: string;

constructor(document: Document) {
Object.assign(this, document);
}

public someGetter() {
return this.something;
}
}

// DynamoDB SingleTable design noSQL btw
document: Document = getDocumentfromDatabase(id);
documentInstance: Document = new Document(document);

// Yeah that looks fine to me - TS
myString: string = documentInstance.someGetter();
```

Why? I assume it has to do with runtime typechecking which doesn't exist but I hoped that if you type the variable at least the methods that exist on that types class Declaration exist on said variables content as well.

Comment: `document` is a built-in object in browser environments, so maybe your editor is just getting confused.

Comment: I am using Intellij IDEA. I will try renaming, thank you very much!